# I can't read and print values from json file

Tags: java, json, deserialization, httpclient, objectmapper

So I'm trying to read and print the json file as a string in the JAVA console. Instead of printing json content, program is printing the default attribute values of reference class. How can I resolve this problem? My code is like this

```
public class test {

 

       private static final String WEATHER_URL = "https://api.collectapi.com/weather/getWeather?data.lang=tr&data.city=istanbul";
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .GET()
                    .header("content-type", "application/json")
                    .header("authorization", "apikey myapikey")
                    .uri(URI.create(WEATHER_URL))
                    .build();
    
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());




//parse JSON into objects 
    
    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
mapper.setVisibility(VisibilityChecker.Std.defaultInstance().withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));

List<Data>data = mapper.readValue(response.body(), new TypeReference<List<Data>>() { });


   
        System.out.println(data);

//CONSOLE OUTPUT
[Data{date=null, day=null, icon=null, description=null, status=null, degree=0.0, min=0.0, max=0.0, night=0.0, humidity=0}]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
```

//DATA CLASS

```
public class Data {
  
  

      private String date;
        private String day ; 
        private String icon ; 
        private String description;
        private String status ;
        private double degree;
        private double min;
        private double max ; 
        private double night ; 
        private int humidity;
```

//getters and setters are here

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" + "date=" + date + ", day=" + day + ", icon=" + icon + ", description=" + description + ", status=" + status + ", degree=" + degree + ", min=" + min + ", max=" + max + ", night=" + night + ", humidity=" + humidity + '}';
    }
```

//JSON FILE STRUCTURE IS LIKE THIS

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "date": "24.09.2018",
      "day": "Pazartesi",
      "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/143/143769.svg",
      "description": "açık",
      "status": "Clear",
      "degree": "31",
      "min": "11.6",
      "max": "31",
      "night": "11.6",
      "humidity": "17"
    },
    {
      "date": "25.09.2018",
      "day": "Salı",
      "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/143/143769.svg",
      "description": "yağmurlu",
      "status": "Rainy",
      "degree": "24.14",
      "min": "7.63",
      "max": "25.82",
      "night": "9.09",
      "humidity": "35"
    },
    "..."
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add Apache common utils to pom and it will work like charm**

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils; 
    
    

String theJsonString = ""; 
    
     
 
 theJsonString=IOUtils.toString(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/path/file.json"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have parsed the response seems wrong to me. JSON file structure response doesn't start with a JSONArray, the actual JSON response is an object which has a key named `result` which is an array of `JSONObject`, so the line below won't work here.

```
List<Data>data = mapper.readValue(response.body(), new TypeReference<List<Data>>() { });
```

`response.body()` isn't returning an array it's an object, so if you want to get array out of the response you need to first get the `result` and then you can parse the array.

You may need to update the POJO first:

```
    public class Response {
        private Data result;
    }

    class Data {
        private String date;
        private String day ;
        private String icon ;
        private String description;
        private String status ;
        private double degree;
        private double min;
        private double max ;
        private double night ;
        private int humidity;
    }
```

Then something like this can parse:

```
final Response response = mapper.readValue(response.body(), new TypeReference<Response>() { });
final List<Data> data = response.result
```

Comment: How can I access result? response.result is not working . Are we talking about the field of Response class?